# JavaFX removeEventHandler not working as expected

Tags: javafx, eventhandler

I'm trying to remove the event handler from a FontAwesomeIconView object but it's not working. The event handler keeps working and I don't know why.

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> glowIcon = (e) -> {
        FontAwesomeIconView icon = (FontAwesomeIconView) e.getSource();

        icon.setFill(Color.web("#ffb521"));
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    };

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> unglowIcon = (e) -> {
        FontAwesomeIconView icon = (FontAwesomeIconView) e.getSource();

        icon.setFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    };

    if (Session.getSession().isProjectCreator()) {
        newIcon.setFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        newIcon.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, glowIcon);
        newIcon.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, unglowIcon);
    }else {

        newIcon.setFill(Color.web("#e8e8e8")); //It's changed to this color
        newIcon.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, glowIcon);
        newIcon.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, unglowIcon);
    }
```

In the beginning the event handlers are ADDED, but when I remove them they keep working, when they shouldn't.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: @AwesomeGuy code snippets are not runnable on others machines post a [mcve] if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a minimal reproducible example it is hard to tell. The most likely scenario from the code that you have posted is that glowIcon/unglowIncon are pointing at different lambdas when you add the handler vs remove it.

Every time this code runs it will assign a different lambda reference to those variables, even if everything is exactly the same.

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> glowIcon = (e) -> {
    FontAwesomeIconView icon = (FontAwesomeIconView) e.getSource();

    icon.setFill(Color.web("#ffb521"));
    scene.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
};
```

The solution is to make sure they are only called once and the reference to them is kept in your controller for as long as they are needed. Using final is a good defensive technique to make sure you don't accidentally reassign it somewhere and lose the reference you need to remove the handler.

Something like:

```
public class GlowController {
    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> glowIcon = (e) -> {
        FontAwesomeIconView icon = (FontAwesomeIconView) e.getSource();

        icon.setFill(Color.web("#ffb521"));
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    };

    private final EventHandler<MouseEvent> unglowIcon = (e) -> {
        FontAwesomeIconView icon = (FontAwesomeIconView) e.getSource();

        icon.setFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    };

    public void doSomething() {
        if (Session.getSession().isProjectCreator()) {
            newIcon.setFill(Color.web("#000000"));
            newIcon.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, glowIcon);
            newIcon.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, unglowIcon);
        }else {

            newIcon.setFill(Color.web("#e8e8e8")); //It's changed to this color
            newIcon.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, glowIcon);
            newIcon.removeEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, unglowIcon);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this when trying to figure out why removing event listeners add with:

```java
vbox.setOnMouseClicked(eventHandler);
```

do not get removed with `removeEventHandler`. It turns out that you need to add your event handler using:

```java
vbox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, eventHandler);
```

for the remove call to work.

I would have thought that it would work regardless of the way you added your handler, but it doesn't :|

Comment: this is the correct answer, thank you.